# "New Toolbar" doesn't remember order

Tags: windows-7

I have added a new toolbar on my taskbar:
[image]

I have set it to a folder. However whenever I rearrange the items through the toolbar, it does remember the order until I logout and login (or reboot etc). It then resets it back to alphabetically ordered

Is this just a bug or am I missing something? Also the sorting scheme within the folder doesn't seem to affect it.

Before logout:
[image]

After login:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug. I actually believe that it is intended behavior that the toolbar items are sorted by name.

They even allow you to prematurely sort the list items by name:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Upon logout/login, the items are put in alphabetical order. There is no way to change this behavior that is built into windows.